# What's the translation of "ratcheting" in French to designate a sequencing technique used in music production?

Tags: traduction, musique

From https://learningmodular.com/patching-a-ratcheting-sequence/:

> [Ratcheting](https://learningmodular.com/glossary/ratcheting/) is a [Berlin School](https://learningmodular.com/glossary/berlin-school/) sequencing technique where an individual note in a sequence has its [envelopes](https://learningmodular.com/glossary/envelope/) retriggered [multiple](https://learningmodular.com/glossary/multiple/) times, usually at a musical subdivision of the sequence’s tempo – such as playing 1/32 notes in the middle of an 1/8 note sequence – to create a roll or what I sometimes (quite improperly) call a trill. Originally attributed to Tangerine Dream (listen to their 1975 track [Stratosfear – especially staring at the 3:00 mark](https://youtu.be/Dpp9ulYMBcc?t=3m) – for a percussive example), ratcheting is appearing more often as a feature in sequencers and [trigger](https://learningmodular.com/glossary/trigger/) controllers these days; Doepfer has even released [a “ratcheting controller” module](http://www.doepfer.de/a1605.htm).

or from https://electronicmusic.fandom.com/wiki/Ratchet:

> A [sequencing](https://electronicmusic.fandom.com/wiki/Sequencer) technique in which some mechanism is used to generate a finite number of [gate](https://electronicmusic.fandom.com/wiki/Gate) or [trigger](https://electronicmusic.fandom.com/wiki/Trigger) signals very quickly, often with an accelerando or decelerando effect.  The resulting gate or trigger is often used to produce a sharp, quick percussion sound, producing an effect sometimes referred to as the "squeaky door sound".  [Tangerine Dream](https://electronicmusic.fandom.com/wiki/Tangerine_Dream) was known for creating ratchet effects by feeding a sequencer with multiple clock lines running at different speeds and rapidly switching from one to the other, but dedicated ratchet generator devices are also available.

What's the translation of "ratcheting" in French when used to designate this sequencing technique? Google Translate and [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=Ratcheting) weren't helpful.

Comment: Il y a des synthés avec mode ratchet. Je n'ai jamais vu le terme  *ratcheting* mais on parle de séquences de ratchet. [Qu'est-ce que le Ratchet ?](https://fr.audiofanzine.com/synthe-modelisation/ashun-sound-machines/hydrasynth/forums/t.753143,qu-est-ce-que-le-ratchet.html). C'est le mot anglais qui sert en français, en [allemand](https://www.sequencer.de/synthesizer/threads/ratchet-sequenzen-wie-geht-das.77039/) et probablement beaucoup d'autres langues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je ne connais pas le domaine, mais chez *Roland* on a remplacé « [for modern rolls and ratcheting](https://www.roland.com/global/products/tr-8s/) » par « [pour créer des roulements inhabituels](https://www.roland.com/fr/products/tr-8s/) ». Difficile d'extrapoler à savoir si c'est un oubli, si on considère que ça fait partie d'une catégorie de roulement ou si c'est derrière « inhabituel » que se cache l'idée. On se serait attendu qu'un fabricant d'équipement dans le domaine soit capable de rendre l'idée :

> ...en intégrant des nuances, des accents, des flas, et des
> subdivisions réglables pour créer des roulements inhabituels.
>
> ...using velocity, accents, flams, and adjustable sub-steps for modern
> rolls and ratcheting.

Ailleurs ([gear4music.ch](https://www.gear4music.ch/fr/Enregistrement-and-ordinateurs/Doepfer-A-160-5-Clock-Multiplier-Ratcheting-Controller-4HP/22P0)) on a trouvé « [séquence à cliquet](https://www.gear4music.ch/fr/Enregistrement-and-ordinateurs/Doepfer-A-160-5-Clock-Multiplier-Ratcheting-Controller-4HP/22P0) » ; on ne sait pas si on a transposé le terme de mécanique mais le propos est cohérent :

> Séquences à cliquet
>
> L'A-160-5 peut être utilisé pour une grande variété d'applications de
> multiplication d'horloge. Un exemple important est la génération de
> séquences à cliquet. Un séquenceur normal ne génère qu'un seul signal
> de porte par pas, alors qu'une séquence à cliquet peut avoir plus
> d'une impulsion de porte par pas.

Le *ratchet* c'est un un simple [cliquet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliquet_(m%C3%A9canique)) en mécanique et c'est le principe derrière une [clé dynamométrique](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clef_dynamom%C3%A9trique). Le concept en échantillonnage semble évoquer les caractéristiques ou le comportement du cliquet sur la route dentée et il n'y a aucune raison pour l'emprunt intégral à mon avis. De plus, on est capable de former *cliquet[age](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-age)* avec le subtantif pour dénoter l'action ou son résultat.

Possiblement que pas un francophone sur mille ne peut spontanément traduire le terme *ratchet* et encore moins l'action sur laquelle il est basé et à mon avis l'emprunt intégral encourage l'ignorance terminologique et la perception de haute voltige sémantique attribuée à la langue anglaise alors qu'il n'en est rien. Le terme aura son utilité en italiques entre parenthèses si on n'est pas certain d'avoir trouvé le terme consacré. Il faut questionner davantage des professionnels dans le milieu.

Comment: Ratchet, ratchet... il y en avait bien sur les catapultes au Moyen-Age, non? Quoique, ce ne soit plus le domaine de la musique.

Comment: En fait, sur une bonne catapulte, il y a 2 _cliquets_ apparemment, que je pense être l'équivalent de _ratchet_ en anglais? Mais encore une fois, aucune idée si c'est applicable à la musique.